# Recuperar data entre duas datas

Tags: javascript

Preciso fazer um `for` entre duas datas, entrando em cada dia desse período.

```
const firstDate = new Date(_visita.data);
const secondDate = new Date(_visita.dataSaida);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sugiro que se aproveite do [construtor de `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) passando o valor da data que tem somando 1 dia. O construtor irá fazer o respetivo ajuste no final do mês, passando assim para o dia correto do mês seguinte. Desta forma pode ir avançando nos dias até parar no dia desejado.

Exemplo (alterei a construção das suas datas para simplificar):

```js
const firstDate = new Date(2018, 1, 17);
const secondDate = new Date(2018, 2, 22);
let data = firstDate;

while (data <= secondDate){
  console.log(data); //utilizar a data para fazer algo
  data = new Date(data.getFullYear(), data.getMonth(), data.getDate() + 1);
  //                      ^--ano              ^--mês          ^--dia
}
```

Note que o mês passado no construtor começa em `0`, logo o mês `1` é na verdade Fevereiro.